# Fuse create function doesn't run properly

Tags: rust, fuse

Using fuse 0.3.1
Here's my create method

```
    fn create(&mut self, req: &Request, parent: u64, name: &OsStr, mode: u32, flags: u32, reply: ReplyCreate) {
        println!("create(req={:?}, parent={}, name={}, mode={}, flags={})", req, parent, name.to_str().unwrap().to_string(), mode, flags);
        reply.created(&Timespec { sec: 1, nsec: 0 }, &FileAttr {
            ino: (self.registry.keys().len() + 2) as u64,
            size: 100,
            blocks: 0,
            atime: Timespec { sec: 0, nsec: 0 },
            mtime: Timespec { sec: 0, nsec: 0 },
            ctime: Timespec { sec: 0, nsec: 0 },
            crtime: Timespec { sec: 0, nsec: 0 },
            kind: FileType::RegularFile,
            perm: 0,
            nlink: 0,
            uid: 0,
            gid: 0,
            rdev: 0,
            flags,
        }, 0, 0, flags);
    }
```

Not sure what generation and fh param in reply.create is, but I set it 0.
And when I then use `touch /tmp/testfs/abc.txt`
It says, `touch: setting times of '/tmp/testfs/abc.txt': Function not implemented`

Do I need to implement some other function aswell?

Also are there some good docs with example for each operations in rust, currently I'm just experimenting with those function and with no clue on what certain params mean.

Comment: You didn't mention whether the print in `.create()` was printed. Is your system defaulting to `mknod()` instead of `.create()`? You could implement `.mknod()` with a print to verify. Also, another good thing to check is whether both `fuse` and `libfuse-dev` are both installed on the system. Also, another user mentioned they had to add user_allow_other in /etc/fuse.conf to get their system working with their Fuse example.

Comment: @Todd println works when I do cat file.txt. And libfuse-dev fuse is installed. Normal example works with read, stat and readdir. But not able to get it to work with write

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for the fork, fuser 0.12. I wasn't seeing the create function being run. It looks like the lookup function is run first and if it responds with anything besides ENOENT, the create function doesn't get called. If you do reply with an ENOENT in the lookup, touching a file will call the create function.

```
    fn create(&mut self, _req: &Request<'_>, parent: u64, name: &OsStr, mode: u32, umask: u32, flags: i32, reply: ReplyCreate) {
        println!("create called with {:?}", name);
    }

    fn lookup(&mut self, _req: &Request, parent: u64, name: &OsStr, reply: ReplyEntry) {
        println!("Calling lookup: {:?}, {:?}", name, parent);
        reply.error(libc::ENOENT);
    }
```